# Access Function - IsNull

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a function to test if a textbox is null. I am trying to accomplish this because I have a lot to my code and I figured this would be a great way to clean up my code making it easier to read.

Main Code Page

```vb
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim textbox1 As String

textbox1 = Forms![Form1].Text1
MsgBox CheckTextbox(textbox1)

End Sub
```

Function

```vb
Public Function CheckTextbox(textboxA As String)
If IsNull(textboxA) Then
    CheckTextbox = "Yes"
Else
    CheckTextbox = textboxA
End If
End Function
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

A String can not be *Null*, thus:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Dim textbox1 As Variant

    textbox1 = Forms![Form1].Text1.Value
    MsgBox CheckTextbox(textbox1)

End Sub
```

and:

```
Public Function CheckTextbox(textboxA As Variant)

    If IsNull(textboxA) Then
        CheckTextbox = "Yes"
    Else
        CheckTextbox = textboxA
    End If

    ' or simply:
    CheckTextbox = Nz(textboxA, "Yes")

End Function
```